# Does not the Systom.IO.Compression.ZipArchive support multi threading?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

```
            Stream stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

            ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(stream);

            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int j = i;
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var entry = zipArchive.Entries[j];
                    //It Shows error message:"the operation changed the status of the object"
                }));
            }
```

[image: RUNOOB 图标]

I've deleted other any operation on the ZipArvhive instance,however such simple code still show error.
The MSDN docs didn't talked about whether it support multi-threading.

Comment: Hey, please check [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: The default is that none of the instance methods are thread-safe on any class in the framework. If a method is thread-safe it is mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The default expectation to the question of thread safety, on any instance member of any type, is "no" - thread safety of instance state is a very niche requirement that is usually explicitly documented (static state is usually expected to have thread safe protections).

The code and behaviour in your question shows that this expectation is validated, and that the answer in this case remains the default: "no"